# Create a multi-series line flot chart getting data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, flot

I am trying to create a Line Flot Chart with multiple series getting the data from the database.

This is the table I have:

```
Code | Date/Time

-----------------------

A    | 9-10-2016 09:25

B    | 10-11-2016 10:11

C    | 11-10-2016 14:23

A    | 9-10-2016 10:10

B    | 10-11-2016 11:00
```

So, I need to show in the chart the total number of occurrences  for each "Code". In the above table, I have 2 occurrences for code "A", 2 occurrences of code "B" and 1 occurrence of code "C".

I don't have problems creating the flot chat but I am not able to get the proper data into the variables for the time series in the flot chart.

So, how to extract the data form the database using MySQL and PHP ???

Below is the code of the Flot chart that I have for one line series and I need to add all series available in the database, so it could be 10 or it could 100.

I have var d1 and need to add d2, d3, d4.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
var d1 = [<?php print_r($js_array1); ?>];

var data = [{label: "<?php echo $error_code; ?>" , data: d1, lines: { show: true, fill: false }, points: { show: true }, color: "#478514" }
];

var p = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
        xaxis: {
  ticks: 8,
  mode: 'time'
},
yaxis: {
  ticks: 6,
  min: 0
},
grid: {
  backgroundColor: { colors: ['#fff', '#eee'] },
  hoverable: true
},
legend: {
  labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
    return '<a href="$chart_label_link">' + label + '</a>';
  }
        }
});

$.each(p.getData()[0].data, function(i, el){
    var o = p.pointOffset({x: el[0], y: el[1]});
    $('<div class="data-point-label">' + el[1] + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: o.left -10,
        top: o.top -20,
        display: 'none',
        'font-size': '13px'
    }).appendTo(p.getPlaceholder()).fadeIn('slow');
});

function showTooltip(x, y, contents, z) {
    $('<div id="flot-tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 30,
        left: x + 30,
        border: '2px solid',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': '#FFF',
        opacity: 0.80,
        'font-size': '10px',
        'border-color': z,
        '-moz-border-radius': '5px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '5px',
        '-khtml-border-radius': '5px',
        'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        'border-radius': '5px'
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}  

function getMonthName(numericMonth) {
    var monthArray = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var alphaMonth = monthArray[numericMonth];

    return alphaMonth;
}

function convertToDate(timestamp) {
    var newDate = new Date(timestamp);
    var dateString = newDate.getMonth();
    var monthName = getMonthName(dateString);

    return monthName;
}

var previousPoint = null;
var previousPointLabel = null;

$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if ((previousPoint != item.dataIndex) || (previousLabel != item.series.label)) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            previousLabel = item.series.label;

            $("#flot-tooltip").remove();

            var x = convertToDate(item.datapoint[0]);
            y = item.datapoint[1];
            z = item.series.color;

            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                    "<b>" + item.series.label + "</b><br />" + y + " transactions impacted.",
                    z);
        }
    } else {
        $("#flot-tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;
    }
    });
});
```

I will appreciate your help... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a post or get method to pull data from the database, this will usually get you a json array which you will then need to turn into an object or assign to a series of variables that can be created as needed to hold the recieved data.

I would suggest looking at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp for some basics on interacting with a mysql database via PHP. Hope that helps!